# Android games not working on Bluestacks

Tags: android, google-play-games, bluestacks

I am trying to play android games on pc using Bluestacks latest offline version. Some games like temple run are working fine in Bluestacks. But some more games like Candy Crush Saga, Dot,etc.. are not working and cannot be installed on bluestacks. I have searched it on google. But im unable to find the solution. Can anyone help me to play these games on PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [GenyMotion](http://www.genymotion.com/) instead and follow the guide at [XDA: Installing ARM Translation and GApps](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952) to get better support for native code running on an x86 VM.

Even with this, many games may still not work since they are compiled for ARM processors and any decent performing VM will be running an x86 image.

Answer (score 2):

Try [DuOS-m](http://www.amiduos.com) (http://www.amiduos.com). Candy crush saga and D.O.T are working great; plus the performance (especially 3D) is excellent.